# Kann man „du“ auf Spielkarten groß schreiben?

Tags: capitalization

Ich habe mir den [Duden-Artikel](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Gross-oder-Kleinschreibung-von-duDu-und-ihrIhr) dazu durchgelesen, aber es ist mir nicht klar geworden, welcher Fall bei der Beschriftung auf Spielkarten hier zutrifft. Kann man „du“ dort groß schreiben? (z.B. bei "Magic the Gathering")

Comment: Ganz grundsätzlich: Ob du es kannst oder nicht, wissen wir nicht. Wir können dir höchsten sagen, ob es dann richtig oder falsch ist.

Answer (score 8):

Hier gibt es kein „richtig“ oder „falsch“: Bis zur Rechtschreibreform war die Anrede „Du“ oder „Sie“ aus Höflichkeit stets großzuschreiben. Inzwischen lautet die Regel (K 83) im Duden, dass die Höflichkeitsform „Sie“ großgeschrieben wird, beim vertrauteren „Du“ ist es dem Schreiber freigestellt.

Comment: "Bis zur Rechtschreibreform war die Anrede „Du“ oder „Sie“ aus Höflichkeit stets großzuschreiben." - eigentlich nur in Briefen und vergleichbaren direkten Ansprachen.

Comment: Ja, eben bei der Anrede – durchaus auch in der Wiedergabe direkter Rede, zumindest beim Sie.